# Janusgraph spark guava version

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, graph, guava, janusgraph

Here is my problem:

We are using cloudera 5.7.0 with java 1.8.0_74 and we have spark 1.6.0, janusgraph 0.1.1, hbase 1.2.0.

I run the following code in gremlin shell:

```
:load data/call-janusgraph-schema-groovy
writeGraphPath='conf/my-janusgraph-hbase.properties'
writeGraph=JanusGraphFactory.open(writeGraphPath)
defineCallSchema(writeGraph)
writeGraph.close()

readGraph=GraphFactory.open('conf/hadoop-graph/hadoop-call-script.properties')
gRead=readGraph.traversal()
gRead.V().valueMap()

//so far so good everything works perfectly

blvp=BulkLoaderVertexProgram.build().keepOriginalIds(true).writeGraph(writeGraphPath).create(readGraph)
readGraph.compute(SparkGraphComputer).workers(1).program(blvp).submit().get()
```

It stars executing the spark job and first stage runs smoothly however at the second stage I get an Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.idassigner.StandarIdPool.waitForIDBlockGetter(StandartIDPool.java:136).......
```

I think it is a guava version problem

Here is how I start the gremlin shell

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/hdfs/jdk.1.8.0_74

export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR= /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn
export YARN_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hadoop-yarn
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_CONF_DIR
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=$SPARK_HOME/conf
export HBASE_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hbase
export HBASE_CONF_DIR=$HBASE_HOME/conf

source "$HADOOP_CONF_DIR"/hadoop-env.sh
source "$SPARK_HOME"/bin/load-spark-env.sh
source "$HBASE_CONF_DIR"/hbase-env.sh

export JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.library.path=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/hadoop/lib/native -Dtinkerpop.ext=ext -Dlog4j.configuration=conf/log4j-console.properties -Dgremlin.log4j.level=$GREMLIN_LOG_LEVEL -javaagent:/mnt/hdfs/janusgraph-0.1.1-hadoop2/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar -Dhdp.version=$HDP_VERSION"

GREMLINHOME=/mnt/hdfs/janusgraph-0.1.1-hadoop2
export HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS=$GREMLINHOME/lib

export CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HBASE_HOME/conf

export CLASSPATH=$GREMLINHOME/lib/*:$YARN_HOME/*:$YARN_CONF_DIR:$SPARK_HOME/lib/*:$SPARK_CONF_DIR:$CLASSPATH

cd $GREMLINHOME
export GREMLIN_LOG_LEVEL=info
exec $GREMLINHOME/bin/gremlin.sh $*
```

and here is my conf/hadoop-graph/hadoop-call-script.properties file:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
gremlin.hadoop.GraphInputFormat=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.io.script.ScriptInputFormat
gremlin.hadoop.inputLocation=/user/hive/warehouse/tablex/000000_0
gremlin.hadoop.scriptInputFormat.script=/user/me/janus/script-input-call.groovy
gremlin.hadoop.outputLocation=output
gremlin.hadoop.jarsInDistributedCache=true

spark.driver.maxResultSize=8192
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=5000
spark.executor.cores=1
spark.executor.instances=1000
spark.master=yarn-client
spark.executor.memory=10g
spark.driver.memory=10g
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
```

If I change the line "spark.master=yarn-client" to "spark.master=local[*]" then it runs perfectly and loads the data to the janusgraph, no exception is thrown. However I need to use yarn, it is a must for me. Thus I added the guava-18.0.jar to hdfs and add the line "spark.executor.extraClassPath=hdfs:///user/me/guava-18.0.jar" to hadoop-call-script.properties.
It did not solve the problem.

Currently I am out of ideas and helpless, any help is appreciated.

Not: I am aware that mvn shading is something related to this problem, however in this case since I am using janusgraph codes to create a spark job I am not able to intervene and shade the guava packages.

Thx in advance,
Ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs when you submit a Spark job that will use Janusgraph to read/write from/to HBase. The real cause of the problem is each of this component requires a different version of guava which has very fast-paced commits and compatibility between versions is not ensured. Here is quick look at version dependency -

- Spark v1.6.1 - Guava v14.0.1
- HBase v1.2.4 - Guava v12.0
- Janusgraph 0.1.1 - Guava v18.0

Even if you make all three jars available in CLASSPATH you will keep getting guava specific due to the conflicting versions. The way I solved it was by rebuilding Janusgraph and shading guava with relocation in janusgraph-core and janusgraph-hbase-parent.

After resolving this I encountered few other dependency issues related to jetty conflicts in Spark and HBase, for which I excluded mortbay from janusgraph-hbase-parent shading.

Hope this helps, if you need more information on this I shall update the answer.

Comment: Your answer certainly helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the exact same problem few days back. This happens because com.google.guava:guava:18.0 artifact might not be present in the classpath or there might be multiple versions of the same jar present on the classpath.

```
#from the projects home dir
>ls -lrt lib/ | grep gua
# should show guava-18.0.jar
```

If the artifact(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/18.0 ) is not present then add it into lib folder.

It is good to print the $CLASSPATH from within the shell script to check if required jars are on the classpath